# How to drop a div between two other divs

Tags: html, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a page with a number of DIV's on. I want to be able to click on a div and drag it to a new position.  When I drop the div I want the other divs on the page to "make room" and move along! So my page looks like so.

[image: Divs on page]

I am using jQuery EasyUI to make the divs "draggable" but when I drop the div in the new position I get...

[image: What I don't want]

What I want is the div to "snap" into place like this....

[image: What I want]

I have looked for clues on how to do this but cannot find it. I would really appreciate any pointers or even hints.

**EDIT:**  I should add that this is all held in an MVC view.

Comment: I think this link contains what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/76yRN/1/

Comment: Good news: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for!  Bad news is I can substitute the code you have in your fiddle with the code I have in my page and all works exactly as I want it to. However it doesn't work in my page.  When I drop the div it just snaps back to its original position!

Comment: My fiddle in case anyone can see what could be wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/Wurzel/WWGRX/1/

Comment: @NNzz That gave me all I needed the reason it wasn't snapping to start with was my fault, I had left a reference to easyui js file in the page!  Thank you!